# Blender 2.8 manual vertex coordinate editing

Tags: vertices

In blender 2.79 vertex coordinates were able to be edited directly in the window.
In 2.80 this functionality appears to be absent, is there any way to bring this functionality back?

Answer (score 8):

feel quite dumb with this one, the Sidebar is less visible and toggled off by default (for my install at least). The data can be found by toggling it on (pressing N).

Comment: Would be great to know how to bulk edit them. Selecting more than one and setting a value causes strange results. Where setting each one at a time works. It would be nice to select a row and set them all to Z 0 to ground them, for example.